# Golang High GC pause times on docker/kubernetes

Tags: go, docker, kubernetes

I am migrationg a web application written in Go from *AWS Elastic Beanstalk* to *Kubernets* and I noticed that the garbage collector pause times (I am using Newrelic to monitor the application) increased about a 100 when running the application.

I believe it is related with the CPU limiting that the Kubernet does.

Does anyone have any idea about what is really causing it?  Is it possible to overcome it?

Below there is a small example of this difference.

**Elastc Beanstalk:**

[image: GC Pause time - Elastic Beanstalk]

**Kubernets:**

[image: GC Pause time - Kubernets]

After some tests and more research I discovered some interesting things.
The CPU limit on Docker seems to have a great influence on GC time/pauses. After some tests I got the CPU limit to `500m` which means about 1/2 CPU of a 8-core machine.

I set `GOMAXPROCS = 1` and `GOGC = 1000` and this lead to less and faster GC pauses, however the average memory usage increased.

Here are a 27h overview of Kubernets and Elastic Beanstalk

**Kubernetes:**

[image: GC overview - Kubernetes]

**Elastic Beanstalk:**

[image: GC overview - Elastic Beanstalk]

Comment: what go version did you use to build the binaries

Comment: You haven't provided any code, any memory stats, any system specifications, any gctrace output, any pprof data, or any system profiling information. There really is nothing here to help solve the problem. If you want to know what the garbage collector is doing, start by looking at the GODEBUG gctrace output.

Comment: @RickyA I'm using Go 1.8 on both environments.

Comment: @JimB I will collect some of this information you asked for.  However I cannot really provide any code because of my NDA :/

Comment: The logs I got from gctrace on beanstalk were corrupted :/

I will update the question with a 27h comparison of both environments and some settings helped to get faster gcpauses